# SerializationException: Type UnityEngine.GameObject is not marked as Serializable. but it is

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to save stuff  using this

```
{
       if(File.Exists(Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.timeline"))
        {
            BinaryFormatter Bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.timeline", FileMode.Open);
            PlayerData Data = Bf.Deserialize(stream) as PlayerData;
            stream.Close();
            return Data.Stats;
        }
```

and when I go to do this

```
for (int E = 0;E<Eqipment.Length; E++)
            {
                Eqipment[E] = "NA";
                if (E <Player.equipment.Count)
                {
                    Eqipment[E] = Player.equipment[E].IteamName;
                }
            }
```

I get `SerializationException: Type UnityEngine.GameObject is not marked as Serializable`. But it is

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ItemCard
{
    public string IteamName;
    public string Description;
    public int amount;
    public float HPBosst;

}
```

I'm really confused.

Comment: you're showing the method to serialize "ItemCard", is Player.equipment[E] returning an "ItemCard" ?

Comment: *`im trying to save stuff using this `* That's your `Load` code, as evidenced by the `Deserialize` call. *`UnityEngine.GameObject is not marked as Serializable`* That's a class of `ItemCard` which is not a MonoBehaviour component *or* a GameObject and therefor not the object causing the problem.

Comment: yes there both ItemCards i screwed up but ya  Eqipment[E] = Player.equipment[E]

Comment: yes, there both ItemCards this is why im confused why                     Eqipment[E] = Player.equipment[E]  came up with this error  i just what to copy the information over